# Parsing string in JSON format not permited, Kendo UI chart

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-ui

So I'm trying to create a chart using kendo UI and it's basically like this:

```
$("#chart2016").kendoChart({
                    title: {
                        text: "2016 CHART"
                    },
                    legend: {
                        position: "bottom"
                    },
                    series: rawData
                });
```

`rawData` accepts JSON values like this:

```
var rawData = [ { name: rData[0].category_code, data: [rData[0].numb] },
                { name: rData[1].category_code, data: [rData[1].numb] },
                { name: rData[2].category_code, data: [rData[2].numb] },
                { name: rData[3].category_code, data: [rData[3].numb] },
                { name: rData[4].category_code, data: [rData[4].numb] } ];
```

But I was accepting an array, and I want to show everything inside the array, so using a loop I parsed a string in that format using these codes, so I can display everything inside the array:

```
                var i;
                var rawData;
                for(i = 0; i < rData.length; i++){
                    if(rData.length == 0){
                        rawData = "[{name: " + "There is no data!" + ", data: [0] }]";
                    }
                    else if(i == 0){
                        rawData = "[ { name:" + rData[i].category_code +
                            ", data: [" + rData[i].numb + "] },";
                    }
                    else if(i == rData.length - 1){
                        rawData += "{ name:" + rData[i].category_code +
                            ", data: [" + rData[i].numb + "] } ]";
                    }
                    else{
                        rawData += "{ name:" + rData[i].category_code +
                            ", data: [" + rData[i].numb + "] },";
                    }
                }
```

I was successful in copying the format, but the problem I think is that it won;t accept a string in JSON format, is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: *"rawData accepts JSON values like this:"* - The example you give is not JSON, it's an array of objects. Why are you trying to build your `rawData` as a string rather than just creating an empty array (`rawData = []`) and adding objects to it (`rawData.push({name: "There is no data!", data: [0]})`)?

Comment: thank you so much, it worked!! I'm sorry, i'm sort of a newbie